# Picasso OutOfMemoryError:

Tags: android, picasso

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= content.getPptPageCount(); i++) {
                        final String thumbNailPath = ImageUtils.getThumbNailPathsForLocalContent(contentID, i);
                        final Bitmap bmp = Picasso.with(AppManagers.getAppContext().getContext())
                                .load(ProxyPathHandler.getProxyURLSlide(content.getPresentationFileID(), i))
                                .get();
                        ImageUtils.writeBitmapToFile(bmp, thumbNailPath);
                        thumbNailPathList.add(thumbNailPath);
                    }
```

While trying to `get()` bitmap from `Picasso` I am getting this error

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 49486856
>   byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 31MB until OOM
>         at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method) ~[na:0.0]
>         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method) ~[na:0.0]
>         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:773)
>   ~[na:0.0]
>         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:749)
>   ~[na:0.0]
>         at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.decodeStream(BitmapHunter.java:142)
>   ~[na:0.0]
>         at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:217) ~[na:0.0]
>         at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.get(RequestCreator.java:396)
>   ~[na:0.0]
>         at com.allego.android.app.manager.ContentManager$70.call(ContentManager.java:2969)
>   ~[na:0.0]
>         at com.allego.android.app.manager.ContentManager$70.call(ContentManager.java:2947)
>   ~[na:0.0]
>         at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual(SingleFromCallable.java:35)
>   ~[na:0.0]
>         at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2702) ~[na:0.0]
>         at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
>   ~[na:0.0]
>         at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:451) ~[na:0.0]
>         at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
>   ~[na:0.0]

I kinda can solve this by adding

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

But I would like to find another solution,thx in advance.

Comment: You're loading in a 50MB image.  That's going to give you troubles even on modern devices, much less older ones.  Why is your image that big, and can you use a smaller one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load smaller images. If you are looking for thumbnails, you should have a service that scales the images to thumbnail sizes. Maybe 160x160 px and manage it that way. You are handling far too large of images.

However, if you insist on using large images, you can at least allow Picassa to scale them for you or Glide.

For example. Glide can do override size so you don't spend all the memory resource over drawing the pixels.

```
Glide
 .with(context)
 .load(yourImageUrl)
 .override(200, 200)
 .into(imageView);
```

Picassa will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate how much memory is needed for allocation for an image as the below:

```
Memory (Byte) = width(pixel) * height(pixel) * sf (scaling factor) * depth (bytes/pixel)
```

where:
**width and height:** are image dimensions **to pixel**.
**sf:** **phone density** (dp/pixel ration). For example in a phone with 480 dpi specification => 480/160 = 3 or xxhdpi
**depth:** **bit depth** of the image. For example, you can find this value by a simple Linux command: `identify -verbose fullImageName`.

I hope this helps you.